# Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-marketing-api

I am working on creating campaigns using facebook marketing api with java code. I am successfully created campaign and adset and targeting stuff but when i created creative it shows me this error

> com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIException$FailedRequestException: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1885183,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode","error_user_msg":"Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.","fbtrace_id":"DIS5OUWvh0Y"}}
>    at com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIRequest.readResponse(APIRequest.java:304)
>    at com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIRequest.access$100(APIRequest.java:53)

After getting this error i make my app public but now i am unable to create any thing like campaign or ad set  and this time api show me this error

> com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIException$FailedRequestException: {"error":{"message":"(#294) Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission for ads_management","type":"OAuthException","code":294,"fbtrace_id":"CmN3BD1aQlQ"}}
>    at com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIRequest.readResponse(APIRequest.java:304)
>    at com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIRequest.access$100(APIRequest.java:53)

I am stuck between these both exceptions. Need help on it.

Comment: Did you submit your app for review, to get all the relevant stuff approved by Facebook …?

Comment: Yes, I have submitted and after that it go live

Comment: Did you _just_ submit it, or was it actually reviewed and approved by Facebook …?

Comment: In App Review page there is a toggle button which is asking Make TestApp public? I clicked it to Yes. 
Than it shows this message
You must provide a valid Privacy Policy URL in order take your app Live. Go to Basic Settings and make sure it is valid.

I filled the manadatory fields than click on Make TestApp public

After that i clicked on taggle button "Status"" on right top 

Now status is showing Live

Comment: That has nothing to do with review. If your app does not let you ask the user to grant `ads_management` in live mode, then that means you need to submit your app’s use of that permission for review & approval by Facebook first.

Comment: Is there any way to add creative in development mode app?